# Convert text into dictionary with python

Tags: python, parsing, converters

I have a text (output of sercmd command)

```
{
    SET_NO: 9
    SET: {
            SET_ID: 7
            DEST: {
                    URI: sip:host2:5060
                    FLAGS: IP
                    PRIORITY: 0
                    ATTRS:
            }
            DEST: {
                    URI: sip:host1:5060
                    FLAGS: AP
                    PRIORITY: 0
                    ATTRS:
            }
...
```

What is the best way to convert output like this into dictionary? Is it the only way to use regexp and add quotes?
I looked for a while and didn't find the solution, so hope it's not a duplicate

Actually I need to generate strings for each dest

```
<FLAGS> <SET_ID> <URI>
```

like

```
ap 7 sip:host1:5060
```

Comment: You can always use `pyparsing`. Out of interest, what generates this file format?

Comment: @xr09: No, that is not JSON.

Comment: @wRAR: that's output of sercmd command. I can do the parsing but I hope there is something more simple - as I want to parse not just this single output

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source of `sercmd` I don't think this is a particular specific format like `json`, that you can parse with a dedicated parser, so you will have to make your own.

But since the [help](https://github.com/flowroute/kamailio/blob/master/utils/sercmd/EXAMPLES) indicates that you can generate a more easy to parse (but less pleasing to the eye) output like [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) you should look into that if you can run `sercmd` and are not stuck with some existing output files.